# GET form not being passed correctly

Tags: php, get

I have a get form on a store website. The idea is, as you click on the "Add to Cart button" it sends the parameters (3 out of 4 are already known, being the last one an user input). The problem here is that the URL sent is not correct.

Here's an example of a form for one product:

```
<div class='product'>
    <article class="produto_box">
        <h3>Salsa</h3>
        <img src='https://gnomo.fe.up.pt/~ee10174/trabalhosSiem/trabalhoPHP2/images/ervas/salsa'.'.png'>
        <br>
        <span class="preco"><b>Preço: </b>1€</span>
            <form method="GET" action="https://gnomo.fe.up.pt/~ee10174/trabalhosSiem/trabalhoPHP2/actions/produtos/add_to_cart.php?preco=1&qtd=qtd&id=4&nome=Salsa>
                <input type="hidden" name="encomendar[4][preco]"  value="1" />
                Qtd (1-10): <input type="number" name="qtd" min="1" max="10"><br>
                <input type="submit" name="encomendar[4]" value="Adicionar ao Carrinho">
            </form>
    </article>
</div>
```

Generated by:

```
{foreach $produtos as $produto}
    <div class='product'>
        <article class="produto_box">
            <h3>{$produto.nome}</h3>
            <img src='{$BASE_URL}/images/{$produto.tipo}/{$produto.ref}'.'.png'>
            <br>
            <span class="preco"><b>Preço: </b>{$produto.preco}€</span>
            {if $TIPO == 'cliente'}
                <form method="GET" action="{$BASE_URL}/actions/produtos/add_to_cart.php?preco={$produto.preco}&qtd=qtd&id={$produto.id}&nome={$produto.nome}>
                    <input type="hidden" name="encomendar[{$produto.id}][preco]"  value="{$produto.preco}" />
                    Qtd (1-10): <input type="number" name="qtd" min="1" max="10"><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="encomendar[{$produto.id}]" value="Adicionar ao Carrinho">
                </form>
            {/if}
        </article>
    </div>
{/foreach}
```

Instead of the desired URL, I get this passed:

```
(...)add_to_cart.php?qtd=3&encomendar%5B4%5D=Adicionar+ao+Carrinho
```

Any idea why does this happens?

Comment: if I understand your question correctly - you need to use urlencode() on the full url

Comment: @JasonButler, how exactly should I do that? I tried to do "action = urlencode(url)" but it isn't working, assumes that the urlencode is part of the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode the URL, but you should really use POST and not GET if you want to accept any input. You will get into a lot of encoding problems with GET.

Comment: I thought about this, the problem is that I don't really know how to retrieve the variables on POST, using this way of declare them. Qtd would be easy, but how could I manage the ones who are generated dynamically?

Comment: In PHP, $_REQUEST['encomendar'] should be an array, exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use smarty so you may have to fix my syntax a little, but I think this is approximately what you need:

```
{assign var="url" value="{$BASE_URL}/actions/produtos/add_to_cart.php?preco={$produto.preco}&qtd=qtd&id={$produto.id}&nome={$produto.nome}" }
<form method="GET" action="{$url|urlencode}">
```